# Add outer border to the wpf grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I ve got simple grid in my wpf app, I would like it to hace outer border border.

How can I achieve this ?

thanks for any hints

Comment: Please show some effort, at least in googling the question.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put your `Grid` in a [`Border`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) element:

```
<Border BorderBrush="SlateBlue" BorderThickness="5,10,15,20" 
        Background="AliceBlue" Padding="5" CornerRadius="15">
  <Grid>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

The `Grid` control cannot draw a border of its own.

Comment: would it work if window is full screen and grid set to 640 480 ?

Comment: @gruber How about just giving it a try?

Answer (score 2):

Why not put a `Border` around the `Grid`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
  <Grid>
    <!-- Your view -->
  </Grid>
</Border>
```